# How does one subtract the .Value from the Offset.Value of any given 'i' in a For Each loop?

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, range

I have the following code written in VBA:

```
For Each W In Range("B5:B15000").Cells
    If W.Offset(-1, 0).Value - W.Value > 1.5 Then
        W.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next W
```

The intent is to iterate down 'Column B', between Rows 5 and 15000, subtracting each of the current 'W' values from the Offset 'W' values. If the resultant difference from the equation is greater than 1.5 then delete the entire following 'W'(Offset) row. If the difference is less than or equal to 1.5, move on to the next 'W'.

For a better understanding of the data set, column B is essentially a time stamp series. As you go further down the column, the time stamp increases in varying amounts of seconds. I need to pick out the gaps (so to speak) that are greater than 1.5 seconds and delete them.

Here is a sample of the column data:

[image: data sample]

The task seems simple enough, but I am receiving a 'Type Mismatch' error. I am relatively new to the For Each loop, so I do not quite understand what portions are mismatched.

Comment: Is your `W.Value` formatted as a number?

Comment: @mrbungle Hello! Thanks for responding so quickly. I do not believe it is formatted as a number. How might I go about that efficiently?

Comment: @liamwilt - Edit your question to show what the data in column B looks like.

Comment: My suggestion was just a quick shot in the dark.  I can run this piece of code and it works regardless of text or number format.  But yeah, what @JasonFaulkner said, lets see the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formats are definitely numbers, so you shouldn't get a type mismatch. My guess is row 5 is the first row which contains data so offsetting by -1 to row 4 causes the error because you cannot subtract a string (the header text) and number.

This aside, your logic of going top down could present a problem (in addition the implementation problem of deletion of the iterator, `W`, modifying the collection). Consider this data:

1. 12
2. 13
3. 15
4. 16
5. 17

Going top down would delete row 3 and then compare row 4 to row 2 (since 3 was deleted) and delete it is well since the difference is larger than 1.5 (and so on).

Instead you will want to go bottom up. In the above example, row 5 and row 4 would remain because they would be compared with respect to their intended value with row 3 still being deleted.

The code for that could look something like this:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 15000 to 6 Step -1 '6 because 6-1 would mean 5 is the first row which contains data.
    If Cells(i - 1, "B").Value - Cells(i, "B").Value > 1.5 Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next
```

---

Edit: Going bottom up is still going to leave large gaps in your data. For example in your provided data the following (among others) would be deleted:

- 50
- 31
- 23

Comment: Hey there, thanks for looking into this. So, the type mismatch has vanished (yay!), but in its place we now have an 'Object Required' error. The debug highlight is pointing me toward the beginning of the 'If' statement written in your response.

Comment: @liamwilt - You can probably get rid of the prefix `Sheet` in the method. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Works like a charm, sir! Thank you kindly for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

A *Type Mismatch* error is due to a value that isn't the type you think it is. Most likely, one of the cells is blank, or contains text, or something that's not a number.

Explicit conversion to a `Double` with `CDbl` will likely not fix the *Type Mismatch* error, because if either value is *not a number*, things go boom anyway - implicit conversion or not.

The right thing to do is to handle all the edge cases - you need to decide how to handle values that are *not a number* - here's a function that treats them as `0`:

```
Private Function GetNumericValue(rng As Range) As Double
    Dim result As Double
    On Error Resume Next
    result = CDbl(rng.Value)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then result = 0
    On Error GoTo 0
    GetNumericValue = result
End Function
```

Now you can do this:

```
If GetNumericValue(W.Offset(-1, 0)) - GetNumericValue(W.Value) > 1.5 Then
```

If that still doesn't fix it, and your data is completely made of *what appears to be* numbers, then my bet is on the *decimal separator* character being off. Verify that in Control Panel / Regional Settings. Your spreadsheet seems to be expecting a dot, but your settings might have it as a comma.